# Any DNSBL script to Unbound?

Tags: shell-script, dns, unbound

I know a lot of DNSBL lists (*someonewhocares.org, abuse.ch, malwaredomains.com*, etc...). I wish to know if anyone knows of scripts that can gather these lists (at least some of them) and compile them to a list usable by Unbound.

So I would obtain a file like that:

```
local-zone: "000007.ru" redirect
local-data: "000007.ru A 127.0.0.1"
local-data: "000007.ru AAAA ::1"
...
local-zone: "0.r.msn.com" redirect
local-data: "0.r.msn.com A 127.0.0.1"
local-data: "0.r.msn.com AAAA ::1"
```

That way my unbound instances would block resolution to those domains. I could run the script weekly to update it.

**NOTE:** Ideally, this would be a file served in a `rsync` server to make it efficient to update. I am thinking of sharing it afterwards.

Comment: This list-o-adservers I use in Bind is available in Unbound format - http://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/serverlist.php?hostformat=unbound

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. DNS Zone Blacklist Generator

I came across this projects called [dns-zone-blacklist](https://github.com/oznu/dns-zone-blacklist) which based on its description sounds like what you want.

> This project generates a zone file for [BIND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND), [Dnsmasq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) and [Unbound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbound_(DNS_server)) DNS servers using data from the [StevenBlack/hosts](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts) project. The generated zone files can be used to block ads and malware for an entire network when used with a local DNS server.

To use this blacklist you simply do the following:

*download*

```
$ git clone https://github.com/oznu/dns-zone-blacklist.git
$ cd dns-zone-blacklist
```

*install nodejs*

```
$ npm install
```

*build/compile blacklists*

```
$ node build.js
```

Once built, you'll end up with 3 directories: `./bind`, `./dnsmasq`, and `./unbound`. The resulting configuration file(s) for `unbound` will be located in the `./unbound` directory.

```
$ ll unbound/
total 4852
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 3372150 Jul 16 00:15 unbound.blacklist
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant      64 Jul 16 00:15 unbound.blacklist.checksum
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 1584122 Jul 16 00:15 unbound-nxdomain.blacklist
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant      64 Jul 16 00:15 unbound-nxdomain.blacklist.checksum
```

You would then add these files to Unbound's `/etc/unbound` directory and restart.

#### 2. DNSblacklist

Another option is [DNSblacklist](https://github.com/oznu/dns-zone-blacklist). You do a similar set of steps in pulling this down via `git` into your `/etc/unbound` directory, and configure it using the supplied `unbound.conf` file.

Within the Git repo is a directory, `blackhole`, that includes a shell script, `run.sh`. You simply run the script, `run.sh`, and then check the configuration files using `unbound-checkconf`. If all is good, simply restart Unbound.

#### 3. Using Pi-Hole instead of Unbound

Just a tip but I've been using https://pi-hole.net/ for the last couple of months and really cannot recommend it enough for doing ad blocking at the DNS level. I run it on a ~$35 Raspberry Pi and have even added DHCP + all my internal DNS to it.

The web UI is very easy to navigate and you can add all the lists you want through the UI. Here I've added 50+ lists to my UI and have ~937K domains blocked.

[image: ss1]

[image: ss2]

The lists are getting added under this directory on the device:

```
$ ls /etc/pihole/
adlists.list                               list.20.www.joewein.net.domains            list.3.s3.amazonaws.com.domains             list.59.v.firebog.net.domains
auditlog.list                              list.21.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains  list.40.v.firebog.net.domains               list.5.hosts-file.net.domains
black.list                                 list.22.hostsfile.org.domains              list.41.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains   list.60.v.firebog.net.domains
blacklist.txt                              list.23.someonewhocares.org.domains        list.42.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains   list.61.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains
dhcp.leases                                list.24.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains  list.43.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains   list.62.ransomwaretracker.abuse.ch.domains
GitHubVersions                             list.25.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains  list.44.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains   list.63.v.firebog.net.domains
gravity.list                               list.26.winhelp2002.mvps.org.domains       list.45.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains   list.64.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains
install.log                                list.27.hostsfile.mine.nu.domains          list.46.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains   list.65.zeustracker.abuse.ch.domains
lan.list                                   list.28.v.firebog.net.domains              list.47.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains   list.66.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains
list.0.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains   list.29.adblock.mahakala.is.domains        list.48.github.com.domains                  list.6.hosts-file.net.domains
list.10.reddestdream.github.io.domains     list.2.zeustracker.abuse.ch.domains        list.49.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains   list.7.ransomwaretracker.abuse.ch.domains
list.11.hosts-file.net.domains             list.30.adaway.org.domains                 list.4.s3.amazonaws.com.domains             list.8.v.firebog.net.domains
list.12.reddestdream.github.io.domains     list.31.v.firebog.net.domains              list.50.v.firebog.net.domains               list.9.v.firebog.net.domains
list.13.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains  list.32.s3.amazonaws.com.domains           list.51.s3.amazonaws.com.domains            list.preEventHorizon
list.14.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains  list.33.hosts-file.net.domains             list.52.mirror1.malwaredomains.com.domains  localbranches
list.15.v.firebog.net.domains              list.34.v.firebog.net.domains              list.53.hosts-file.net.domains              local.list
list.16.v.firebog.net.domains              list.35.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains  list.54.hosts-file.net.domains              localversions
list.17.sysctl.org.domains                 list.36.pgl.yoyo.org.domains               list.55.hosts-file.net.domains              logrotate
list.18.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains  list.37.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains  list.56.mirror.cedia.org.ec.domains         pihole-FTL.db
list.19.www.dshield.org.domains            list.38.v.firebog.net.domains              list.57.www.malwaredomainlist.com.domains   setupVars.conf
list.1.mirror1.malwaredomains.com.domains  list.39.v.firebog.net.domains              list.58.bitbucket.org.domains               whitelist.txt
```

#### Black lists

I started with [The Big Blocklist Collection](https://firebog.net/) and followed links to collect all the blacklists that I ended up adding to my Pi-Hole device.

#### References

- [How do I add additional block lists to Pi-hole?](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/how-do-i-add-additional-block-lists-to-pi-hole/259)

Comment: I run my own router, so this solution is actually what I want... But on the router.

Comment: @22decembre - I see, take a look at the updates, I've added 2 such options for Unbound.